# Text binding not working properly

Tags: knockout.js

I've got the following js:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.projects = ko.observableArray([]);
  self.currentProject = ko.observable();

  self.selectProject = function (project) {
    self.currentProject(project);
  };
}
var vm = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(vm);



$(function() {
    $('#spinner-wrapper').show();
    $.getJSON("some/url", function(data){

        vm.projects(data.projects);
        vm.selectProject(data.projects[0]);
    });
});
```

And the following HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" data-bind="foreach: {data:projects, as: 'project'}">
   <li><a href="#" data-bind="text:projectName, click: vm.selectProject"></a></li>
</ul>
<h1 data-bind="text:currentProject.projectName"></h1>
```

So everytime I click an `<a>`, the `selectProject` method get called, and `self.currentProject` changes properly. The problem I have is that `h1` doesn't show anything.

Comment: Current project is an observable object. If you want to access its properties, use `text: currentProject().projectName`. Note that this will throw an exception if `currentProject` isn't defined. Here's a documentation article about this: http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/knockout.js/2249/bindings#t=201607221418051404614&a=remarks-when-to-use-parentheses-0

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried `currentProject().projectName` but, as you said, it throws an exception because when the page first load, it is not yet defined (it is defined on the ajax callback). Any ideas to solve that?

Comment: I'll write down an answer with some ways of solving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `currentProject` property is observable. This means it's a function you'll have to call to *get* your actual property from it. The function doesn't have a property named `pojectName`, so it will return `undefined` (note that it won't throw an error).

If you can be sure `currentProject` always holds an object with a `projectName` property, you can easily fix your data-bind like so:

```
data-bind="currentProject().projectName"
```

(Find out how knockout *gets* and *sets* observables [here](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3297291/user3297291))

**However**, in your view model, `currentProject` is initialized with value `undefined`. Here's some ways of dealing with the undefined value:

1. Use a `with` binding (my personal preference)

A `with` binding doesn't render nor data-binds the HTML it encapsulates if its value isn't properly defined:

```
<h1 data-bind="with: currentProject">
  <span data-bind="text: projectName"></span>
</h1>
```

*Drawbacks*: you'll need an extra element or a virtual binding. Watch out that there aren't any weird flashes when elements are removed...

---

2. Create a computed property in your viewmodel:

   ```
   self.currentProjectName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
     var currentProject = self.currentProject();
     return currentProject ? currentProject.projectName : "";
   });
   ```

*Drawbacks*: clutters your view model. *Pros*: easily create an empty state/placeholder

---

3. Fix it in the data-bind:

   ```
   <h1 data-bind="text:currentProject() ? currentProject().projectName : ''"></h1>
   ```

This is basically the same approach as (2).

*Drawbacks*: clutters your view, prone to bugs.